# ProgressDialog not showing even when I set the show

Tags: android

I have a problem with the ProgressDialog.

My code is:

```
 mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
 mProgressDialog.show(this, "", "loading...");
 if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
 Log.d("debug", "show");
```

But I can't see the debug message...
Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show is an static method ,you should do like this:

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog ;

mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
    "loading...", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [onCreateDialog method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29).

If you use Fragments, use [.show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) method from dialog

You can read about dialogs in Android [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDialogs/article.html)

Comment: I checked the doc on Android developer...
they said onCreateDialog() is deprecated?

Comment: Yes, this is deprecated if you developer your app in fragment logic. If not, you can surely use it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", "loading...", true);
```

to dismiss the dialog

```
    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
        if (mProgressDialog .isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog .dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...
I just tried your suggestion but it's still not working :(

Comment: If the above code is not working you can use ProgressBar widget.